# How to process the returned object from Facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

So, I got this URL from Facebook: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

If you open that up, the URL will return an object. Please teach me how to process that and put it in my website.

I think it has to do with traversing with XML? I don't know.. Please teach me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be JSON. See [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 2):

That page appears to be JSON, not XML. Here is a decent guide to JSON and PHP http://www.itnewb.com/v/Introduction-to-JSON-and-PHP